# Assigning image to key value (Swift)

Tags: swift, uitableview, dictionary, uiimageview

I am trying to assign an image for different majors in my dictionary ex SE, CS, default but each time I run the program it crashes on me. I am using a tableview and have a subtile style. Should I be assigning something to the majors first? Here is my tableviewcontroller

```
import UIKit
class ClassRosterTableViewController: UITableViewController {

    var studentsList = [Dictionary<String, String>]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let myStudentRoster = ClassRosterModel()
        studentsList = myStudentRoster.studentsRoster
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("studentCell", forIndexPath: indexPath)

        // Configure the cell...
        cell.textLabel?.text = studentsList[indexPath.row]["name"]
        cell.detailTextLabel?.text = studentsList[indexPath.row]["number"]
        print("Student's name: \(studentsList[indexPath.row]["name"])")
        print("Student's number: \(studentsList[indexPath.row]["number"])")
        print("Student's email: \(studentsList[indexPath.row]["email"])")

        if let major = studentsList[indexPath.row]["major"] {
            switch (major) {
            case "SE":

                cell.imageView?.image =  UIImage(named:"SE")!

            case "CS":

                cell.imageView?.image =  UIImage(named:"CS")!
            default:
                cell.imageView?.image =  UIImage(named:"default")!
            }
        }

        return cell
    }


//here is my separate class for the studentslist

import Foundation

class ClassRosterModel {

    var studentsRoster = [Dictionary<String, String>] ()
    init () {

        studentsRoster.append(["name": "Kaczynski, Alex", "major" : "SE", "email" : "s\(rand1)@monmouth.edu", "currentTerm" : "Spring", "numberOfCredits" : "\(rand2)" ])
        studentsRoster.append(["name": "O'Rore, Ryan", "major" : "SE", "email" : "s\(rand1)@monmouth.edu", "currentTerm" : "Fall", "numberOfCredits" : "\(rand2)" ])
    }
}
```

Comment: What line crashes, and what is the crash console message? You have a lot off exclamation marks in your code; every one of those means "Please crash me." You cannot be surprised if it _does_ crash; you asked for it.

Comment: Thanks a ton, I didn't know that they had such an influence on the code, removing them and then removing the break points was what was actually the problem and stopped my code from working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are force unwrapping those images and if they are not present in your app's bundle it will crash. `UIImageView`'s `image` property is optional so it's fine to assign those images without unwrapping them:

```
    if let major = studentsList[indexPath.row]["major"] {
        switch (major) {
        case "SE":
            cell.imageView?.image =  UIImage(named:"SE")
        case "CS":
            cell.imageView?.image =  UIImage(named:"CS")
        default:
            cell.imageView?.image =  UIImage(named:"default")
        }
    }
```

Note: if the images aren't present in your bundle, your imageView will be empty, but at least it won't crash.

Comment: Thanks that was the problem. After removing the break points it worked flawlessly.